# Vue router does not reinitialize child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a weird issue with `vue-router`.

I have a simple CRUD app for users.

It consists of four different views:

1. User list and a create button
2. Create view with a form child component which fetches the fields from an api inside of created().
3. User show view
4. User update view with an equal form child component.

If I go the first time on the edit page of the user with the id 1 everything works like a charm.
But if I go back and click on another user and go to the edit page, it will display the form with the values of the user with the id 1 and there is no new ajax request.

It seems that the component will be reused.
I tried to give the form child components different `:key` values but no success.

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Setting the key on the router-view had no success too...

If I reload the browser it will be displayed correctly

Here a example in a nutshell:

My routes:

```
import Index from "./views/Index";
import Show from "./views/Show";
import Edit from "./views/Edit";
import Create from "./views/Create";

export default [
    {
        path: '/admin/users',
        name: 'users.index',
        component: Index
    },
    {
        path: '/admin/users/create',
        name: 'users.create',
        component: Create
    },
    {
        path: '/admin/users/:id',
        name: 'users.show',
        component: Show,
        props: true
    },
    {
        path: '/admin/users/:id/edit',
        name: 'users.edit',
        component: Edit,
        props: true
    },
];
```

Edit component (Create is sme without id):

```
<template>
        <ResourceForm
            resource="user"
            :resource-id="id"
            @cancel="$router.push({name: 'users.index'})"
        />
</template>

<script>
    import ResourceForm from "../../../components/ResourceForm";

    export default {
        components: {ResourceForm},

        props: ['id'],
    }
</script>
```

ResourceForm component:

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitResourceForm">
        <component
            v-for="(field, index) in fields"
            :key="field.name + index"
            :ref="`${field.name}-field`"
            :is="field.component"
            :field="field"
            :validation-errors="getValidationErrors(field)"
        />
        <div class="mt-8 border-t border-gray-200 pt-5">
            <div class="flex justify-end">
                        <span class="inline-flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                            <button type="button" @click="$emit('cancel')"
                                    class="py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue active:bg-gray-50 active:text-gray-800 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                                {{this.cancelText}}
                            </button>
                        </span>
                <span class="ml-3 inline-flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    class="btn">
                                {{this.submitText}}
                            </button>
                        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
<script>
    import _ from 'lodash';
    import api from "../lib/api";
    import Form from "../lib/mixins/Form";

    export default {
        mixins: [Form],
        props: {
            resource: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            resourceId: {
                required: false,
                default: null
            },
            cancelText: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Cancel'
            },
            submitText: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Submit'
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                fields: []
            }
        },
        watch: {
            '$route': function () {
                console.log('route changed');
                this.fetchResourceForm();
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.fetchResourceForm();
        },
        methods: {
            async fetchResourceForm() {
                let route;
                if (this.resourceId !== null) {
                    route = Cms.route('cms.api.forms.show', {
                        resource: this.resource,
                        id: this.resourceId
                    });
                } else {
                    route = Cms.route('cms.api.forms.new', {resource: this.resource});
                }

                const response = await api(route);
                this.fields = response.data.data.fields;
            },

            async submitResourceForm() {
                const formData = this.getFormData();

                try {
                    const foo = {
                        ...Cms.route('cms.api.forms.store', _.pickBy({
                            resource: this.resource,
                            id: this.resourceId
                        })),
                        data: formData
                    };
                    const response = await api(foo);

                    this.$emit('success', response.data.data);

                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.response.status === 422) {
                        this.validationErrors = error.response.data.errors;
                        Cms.flash('error', 'There are validation errors in the form.')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The Cms.route method does generate api routes and has nothing to do with vue-router.

Comment: Can you add some code?
Also where are you storing the data?
How are you making the api call

Comment: How are you passing the id of the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the router from any of the parent component.

```
watch:{
  `$route`:function(route){
     if(route.name === 'users.create'){
       this.fetchData(route.params.id);
     }
   }
},
methods:{
   fetchData:function(id){
     // fetch your data corresponding to the id
     // save the response to store using `commit`.
     // this.$store.commit('SET_FIELDS',response.data.data.fields);
   }
}
```

Then initialise a `mutation` and `state` in the store

```
const state = {
  fields:{}
}

const mutations = {
  SET_FIELDS:(state,value)=>state.fields = value;
}
```

Inside the `ResourceForm` component, you can get the data from `store` using `computed` method.

```
computed:{
  fields:function(){
    return this.$store.state.fields;
  }
}
```

The `fields` value will rendered real-time on changing the route.

Comment: This does not work. I have put the watcher in my form component but it never get triggered: `watch: {
            '$route': function () {
                console.log('route changed');
                this.fetchResourceForm();
            }
        },` . I never see this console.log

Comment: Are you using `vuex`?

Comment: No. Currently not.

Comment: You may need to add `vuex` store to handle data globally. Please let me know if you need me to add detailed answer.

Comment: If you do not mind I would appreciate a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put the user in a `vuex` state and use this state in both component. Or maybe launch the request in `beforeEnter` hook

Comment: I think I cant use beforeEnter because the form component which does the request is not the component which is used by the router. It is a child component.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [In Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) since these guard methods are available in the components because you passed an imported view directly to `vue-router`:

```js
    {
        path: '/admin/users',
        name: 'users.index',
        component: Index // <-- makes Component Guards available in './views/Index.vue'
    },
```

Replace:

```js
created() {
  this.fetchResourceForm();
}
```

with:

```js
  // Fires if you are already on a DYNAMIC route when a uri parameter like :id changes
  // This will for example run if you navigate from `/admin/users/123` to `/admin/users/456`
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    this.fetchResourceForm();
    next()
  },

  // Fires if you switch between different router entries.
  // When you navigate from `/something` to `/another-path
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    this.fetchResourceForm();
    next()
  },
```

However, if you are fetching data inside a component that is inside a Router View then a `watch` will be required as others have suggested but why not just pass the data down as a `prop` instead?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I do now :-) . Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. 
It does not relate to this functionality but to the component which generates the api routes. 
@Rijosh's solution works if someone encounter this problem in vue-router.